# jquery set scroll range limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i set scroll range limit in jquery?
for example i wanna set horizontally scroll limit for my body

```
jQuery(function($){
    var body_width = $("body").width();
    $("body").scrollLeft(body_width);
});
```

Comment: Question id unclear! Add more details to elaborate it or make a Fiddle.